# setTimeout and Get Request

Tags: javascript, html

**html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Github</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="text" style="width:1000px" id="input">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="save">Save</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete">Delete</button>

<script>
    (function () {
        async function saveData() {
            let check = true;

            const http2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http2.open("GET", 'http://localhost:4020/users');
            http2.send();
            http2.onload = () => {
                let users = JSON.parse(http2.responseText);
                for (let i = 0; i < users.value.length; i ++){
                    if(users.value[i] == document.getElementById('input').value)
                        check = false;}

            setTimeout(() => {
                if (check) {
                    const http = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    http.open("POST", 'http://localhost:4020/users');
                    http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    const data = JSON.stringify({value: document.getElementById('input').value});
                    http.send(data);
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        };

        async function deleteData() {
            const http3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http3.open("DELETE", 'http://localhost:4020/users');
            http3.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            const data = JSON.stringify({value: document.getElementById('input').value});
            http3.send(data);

            setTimeout(() => {
                const http4 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                http4.open("GET", 'http://localhost:4020/users');
                http4.send();
                http4.onload = () => {
                    let users = JSON.parse(http4.responseText);
                    for (let i = 0; i < users.value.length; i ++) {
                        console.log(users.value[i]);
                    }
                }
            }, 10);
        };

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            document.querySelector("#save").addEventListener("click", saveData);
            document.querySelector("#delete").addEventListener("click", deleteData);
        }, false);
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'));

app.use('/users',require('./routes/users'));

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 4020;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`));
```

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var router = express.Router();

const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

var array = [];

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  const data = JSON.stringify({ value: array });
  res.send(data);
});

router.post('/', jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
  array.push(req.body.value);
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i ++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
  }
});

router.delete('/', jsonParser, (req, res, next) => {
  array.splice( array.indexOf(req.body.value), 1 );
});

module.exports = router;
```

I tried to make the code simple. I can't quite understand what am I doing wrong. When loading the page the save (saveData) and delete (deleteData) button (which are dealt with the server side i am not working with database yet) my array are not uploading in a responsive way so I tried using setTimeout which wokred partially. However the onload function aren't always responding. Thanks in advance!

It suppose to work like that (I also inserted some console log on server and client side to help debugging, but didn't help much)
For example:

```
save -> joe
array = [joe]
save -> doe
array = [joe, doe]
save -> mary
array = [joe, doe, marry]
delete doe
array = [joe, mary]
```

Comment: You have `async` functions, but nowhere do you make use of [`.then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) or the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword... Those would be far more optimal than `setTimeout()`.